# Wrapping a Component means it loses focus on rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a long form in react. Before, it had a bunch of components that were defined as such:

```
<input
  type='text'
  value={this.state.form.nameOfFormField}
  onChange={this.updateForm('nameOfFormField')} />
```

Where `updateForm` is a function in the form of `(field) => (e) => {}`, to make code reuse easier.

I wanted to make this easier to maintain, so I created a component, `SpecialInput`, which was defined as such:

```
const SpecialInputBuilder = (form, onChange) => ({ field, ..props }) => (
  <input
    type='text'
    value={form[field]}
    onChange={onChange(field)}
    {...props} />
)
```

Now, I could define the Input during render like so:

```
const SpecialInput = SpecialInputBuilder(this.state.form, this.updateForm)
```

And use it in the component like this:

```
<SpecialInput field='nameOfFormField' />
```

Obviously, this is much more succinct. But this also means that the input field will drop focus every time input is entered into the field (i.e., when `updateForm` is called), because `SpecialInput` is defined every time the `render` function is called. Defining a `key` to each element does not seem to at all alleviate the problem. How can I fix this while still using this simpler component? Is there a middle ground?

Comment: the only way I can think of making this work is to define the inputs as items on the react class. aka in componentWillMount you can create a `this.specialInput = SpecialInputBuilder(this.state.form, this.updateForm)` and then use the already defined input in your render.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change your input builder to just be a react component?

```
const SpecialInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <input
      value={props.form[props.field]}
      {...props}
      type={props.type || 'text'}
      onChange={() => props.onChange(props.field)} 
    />
  )
}
```

and just use it the same way.

```
<SpecialInput field='nameOfFormField' onChange={this.updateForm} form={this.state.form} />
```

Comment: If you define `SpecialInput` that way, then `form` is never passed as a prop that I can see?

Comment: @KyleFahringer sorry i forgot to add it to the render portion where you use the component. Updated.

Comment: Regardless, the purpose of using components in such a manner is then defeated - I still have to define `form` and `onChange` props every time I use the `SpecialInput` prop, which is what I was trying to avoid. While this would technically solve the problem, it basically amounts to reverting to using `input` elements everywhere.

Comment: @KyleFahringer that is the React way of doing things. The only other way to use what you already defined I described in a comment. You would have to define those inputs in your willMount function and use the reference to those throughout the lifecycle of the component. I can try and write up a mock solution in my answer if you would like

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your `onChange` call is executing as soon as it's rendered, instead of a reference to a function to be called when the input changes.

```
// this executes immediately
onChange={onChange(field)}

// this is a reference to the function with a prop prepended
onChange={onChange.bind(this,field)}
```

Comment: my question is how did it ever work? his "working" code before had `onChange={this.updateForm('nameOfFormField')}` which shouldn't work as is anyways. that being said I dont think this is the issue he is reporting. its because a new input object is created on every render cycle which resets the cursor and everything associated with it

Comment: `onChange` returns a function in my code which handles the `event` object, i.e. `(field) => (event) => {}`. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the original question - I'll update now.

Comment: You still can't call it with params without either binding it or making an empty function and then passing the params through.

Comment: @Brand you need a `bind` and and `this` as your first param on `=> onChange.bind(this,field, event)`

Comment: `updateForm` is bound in the constructor of the element. I'm not sure what you believe to be the issue here - The `input` elements worked correctly when unwrapped, also using `onChange={this.updateForm('nameOfFormField')}`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which way it's being stored. The issue is that you can't execute the function with parentheses having a value passed in the params.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with whether it's bound or not. If it's bound just use `onChange={this.updateForm}`

Comment: `updateForm (field) { return (event) => { this.setState({ form: { ...this.state.form, [field]: event.target.value } }) }}`

Comment: When the `updateForm` function is called, it returns a function which accepts an event object. There's no issue with it being called upon render, as I understand it, because it does return a proper event handled, a function which accepts an `event` object.

Comment: Ok I think I get you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar approach but ended up changing it to this;

**(1) Input typer child component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FreeTextField extends Component {
  inputValueFn(e) {
    this.props.userInput(this.props.responseObject, e.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="input-group">
            <label>{this.props.buttonText ? this.props.buttonText : "Firstname"}</label>
            <input type={this.props.type} placeholder="" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue} onChange={this.inputValueFn.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FreeTextField;
```

**(2) From the parent component you can specify all relavent child attr via props**

```
// import
import FreeTextField from './pathTo/FreeTextField';

// Initial state
this.state = {
responseObject: {}
}

// onChange it updates the responseObject
    userInput(fieldKey,value) {
        let responseObject = this.state.responseObject;
        responseObject[fieldKey] = value;
        this.setState({responseObject:responseObject});
    }

// component render()
<FreeTextField 
buttonText="First Name" 
type="text" 
formObjectKey="first_name" 
userInput{this.userInput.bind(this)} />
```